# "Data" option is not enabled in my Oracle Sql Developer--(sqldeveloper-23.1.0.097.1607-x64 version)

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

After installing current 2023 version of Oracle Sql developer, I cannot be able to view or insert any data using DATA Option in Sql Developer. Can anyone help me with this problem??

[Oracle SQL Developer] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9KXW.png)

I can able to insert values but couldn't view it using the data option provided at the top.